# How do I share photos with Photos?

Tags: windows-10, mac, nas, photos

I have an automated backup configured via Time Machine.  The backup goes to a NAS server.  I want to access my Photos content from a windows machine by means of the NAS server (WD My Cloud).  The time machine backup is stored in a proprietary format.  I cannot simply navigate to the Photos content and open `myImage.jpg`.  Apple offers an [alternative](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21364?locale=en_US) solution which is to copy the Photos library blog to the NAS device.  Again, this does not accomplish my goal of navigating to `myImage.jpg`.

How can I backup my Photos library in a cross-platform environment?

Comment: Just because a question is difficult to answer is not a reason to downvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied all the pictures stored in the photo library into the Photos folder.  I now store the photos outside the photo library:

> Choose Photos > Preferences, then click General.
>
> Deselect the “Copy items to the Photos library” checkbox.

I found a feature called [WD Sync](http://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=11395).  This feature allows me to sync a folder with the NAS drive.  Sync the pictures folder, containing plain old jpg images now, and now I can access this information from my other computer.  I imagine something similar could be accomplished with cloud services like Dropbox.

This worked, but annoyingly eradicated the original timestamps.  I have to rely on the numbering system to organize the time periods.